# Combining 2 queries into one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries

```
Select * From wp_booking_transaction
Where DATE(launched) >= "2013-10-10" And DATE(launched) <= "2013-11-10" 
And action = 1 status = 1 And type = 2 And student_id = 81569 
Order by launched desc
```

and

```
Select * From wp_booking_transaction 
Where (DATE(launched) >= "2013-10-10" And DATE(launched) <= "2013-11-10" 
And status = 0 And type = 2 And student_id = 81569) And (action = 21 Or action = 20) 
Order by launched desc
```

REQUIREMENT:

Get rows that has `action = 1` but `status = 1` and rows that has `(action = 20 or action = 21)` but `status = 0`.

Thank you!

Comment: "And action = 1 status = 1 " are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     wp_booking_transaction
WHERE    /* Conditions that appeared in both original queries */
         DATE(launched) >= "2013-10-10" 
AND      DATE(launched) <= "2013-11-10"
AND      type = 2 
AND      student_id = 81569
AND      /* Conditions that are different between the two queries */
         ((action = 1 AND status = 1) OR (action IN(20, 21) AND status = 0))
ORDER BY launched DESC
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I was making it hard when it can be made this easy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `UNION`:

```
Select 
    * 
From 
    wp_booking_transaction 
Where 
    DATE(launched) >= "2013-10-10" 
    And DATE(launched) <= "2013-11-10" 
    And action = 1 
    And status = 1 
    And type = 2 
    And student_id = 81569 

UNION ALL

Select 
    * 
From 
    wp_booking_transaction 
Where (
        DATE(launched) >= "2013-10-10" 
        And DATE(launched) <= "2013-11-10" 
        And status = 0 
        And type = 2 
        And student_id = 81569
    ) 
    And (
        action = 21 
        Or action = 20
    ) 
Order by launched desc
```

**BTW** this:

```
And (
        action = 21 
        Or action = 20
    )
```

can be written like

```
And action IN (21,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **union all | distinct** between both queries

```
Select * From wp_booking_transaction
Where DATE(launched) >= "2013-10-10" And DATE(launched) <= "2013-11-10" 
And action = 1 status = 1 And type = 2 And student_id = 81569 
union all
Select * From wp_booking_transaction 
Where (DATE(launched) >= "2013-10-10" And DATE(launched) <= "2013-11-10" 
And status = 0 And type = 2 And student_id = 81569) And (action = 21 Or action = 20) 
Order by launched desc
```

Comment: For using order by twice you need to wrap your queries in  `()`